# VBA can't find and replace a date

Tags: vba, excel

I have a date in A1:

[image]

I want to change the cell like so:

[image]

So I recorded the macro but it doesn't do anything

```
Sub Macro1()

    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Cells.Replace What:="08/01/2018", Replacement:="09/01/2018", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=True
End Sub
```

How to make it work?

Thank you!!

Comment: What are you replacing? All I see is you added a red fill, which can be done with Conditional Formatting.

Comment: And your problem is that you are trying to replace your date like it was text. One way to convert a date to string is to use the [format function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications).

Comment: i'm quite new to vba, can you explain more how to do condtional formatting for a date?

Comment: @Takichiii conditional formatting is an Excel feature, you don't need any VBA code to do it

Comment: please read my question, my primare issue is to find the cell then to replace with something else using VBA! i updated the question as i previously repeated the same date

Comment: @YowE3K OP asked about conditional formatting in a previous comment... TBH the question isn't exactly clear about the purpose. Using find/replace to change the format of a cell strikes me as a roundabout way to do things.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Oops - I had been thinking when I posted my answer "this could be done by conditional formatting", then thought "well, no, there are reasons why that wouldn't work", then looked up and saw comments on the question mentioning conditional formatting, saw your userid, figured I should pick on you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to search/replace with a string, but you actually have a date (i.e. a number) in the cell.

```
Sub Macro1()

    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Cells.Replace What:=CDate("08/01/2018"), Replacement:=CDate("09/01/2018"), LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: You saved me, thank you so much!!!!! I didn't find any hint to the function `CDate`anywhere before

Comment: @Takichiii Pressing F2 in the VBE will bring up the *Object Browser*; select the "VBA" standard library, then find the `Conversion` module: all type conversion functions are there. You can browse the other modules to discover everything else the standar library has to offer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work on my machine..

```
With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Cells.Replace What:=DateValue("08/01/2018"), Replacement:=DateValue("08/01/2018"), LookAt:= _
    xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=True
```